# Laravel excel: slow download, even with queue

Tags: php, excel, laravel, download

I'm using Laravel Excel (3.1 / Maatwebsite) to export data from my application ( Laravel 5.8 ) to an excel file. This is working, however, the process is really slow. I have traced the root of the problem down to my query. The query takes up to 90 seconds sometimes, due to large amounts of data in my database. The query comes from my **EmployeesExport** class and looks like:

```
public function query() {

    return Employee::query()->whereHas('project', function($q){
        $q->where('project_id',  $this->id);
    });
}
```

I decided to tackle this problem by *queueing the export* so that it will be available for download later on and my users can keep working. So I made sure that my **EmployeesExport** uses the proper classes/namespaces/implements etc:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class EmployeesExport implements FromQuery, ShouldQueue {

    use Exportable;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function query() {

        return Employee::query()->whereHas('project', function($q){
            $q->where('project_id',  $this->id);
        });
    }

}
```

Later on, inside a class **PrintController**, the **EmployeesExport** gets called ( I expected queued ) in one method which also stores the name of the file on the project in the database and redirects back.
I made another method to download the file later on when it's done:

```
public function getData(Project $project) {
        $name = '/data/project-' . $project->id . '-' . time() . '.xlsx';
        (new EmployeesExport($project->id))->store($name);

        $project->update(['datafile_name' => $name]);

        return redirect()->back()->with(['msg' => 'Export started!']);
    }

    public function downloadData(Project $project) {
        return \Storage::download($project->datafile_name);
    }
```

All of this works, however, the process is equally slow. I expected the proces to queue so i would be able to continue working in my application and maybe send an email when the process is complete so I would be able to download the file later on. Therefore i have the following questions about my code in order of importance:

1. How can I get my queue to work?
2. How can I improve my query to be better / faster?
3. Is it possible to chain queue and download() so that my download will happen automatic when the queue/process is done?

Comment: You essentially querying the database twice: with whereHas it does a SELECT WHERE EXISTS on your projects table, and then another sub-query with project_id value. Why not do a single with where(‘project_id’, $this->id)? Try profiling the SQL request made to the database using toSql() function of Builder query object.

Comment: Your query looks odd, `$this->id` refers to `Employee.id` and you compare it against `project_id`. That cant be a right column name. Also check your database indexes; you need many millions of rows to have this query take 90 seconds.

Comment: I made that query because it's a belongsToMany relation.